# Restarting Android Application

Tags: android

At the end of my application , i have a button to restart the application..

What is the way to restart an application in the onClick Listener of a button??

I tried doing it by creating an intent with "com.android.action.main"

But it doesnot work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put following code in your `onClick`

```
Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
             .getLaunchIntentForPackage( getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```